# Really strange error on mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this query, and I think it talks by itself:

```
mysql> select id,email from members where email LIKE "%abraham.sustaita@gmail.com%";
+--------+----------------------------+
| id     | email                      |
+--------+----------------------------+
| 272118 | abraham.sustaita@gmail.com | 
+--------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.69 sec)

mysql> select id,email from members where email = "abraham.sustaita@gmail.com";
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,email from members where id = 272118;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The data exists, but it returns empty if I use other than LIKE...

Comment: What's the format of the columns ?

Comment: can you show the table structure? can you make a select length(id),length(email) from email like ......??

Comment: Please show output of `SELECT HEX(email) FROM members WHERE email LIKE "%abraham.sustaita@gmail.com%"` ?

Comment: columns format, not table. And please answer to eggyal.

Comment: @dystroy int and varchar respectively.

Comment: @eggyal, let me check it

Comment: @eggyal mysql> SELECT HEX(email) FROM members WHERE email LIKE "%abraham.sustaita@gmail.com%"
    -> ;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(email)                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 6162726168616D2E737573746169746140676D61696C2E636F6D | 
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)

Comment: If first column is int, there is a more important problem than the email format. Did you make the 3 queries in order just like that ? Is that reproductible ?

Comment: Please `CHECK TABLE members`.

Comment: And rebuild or drop the indexes of this table.

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: this is not a forum. Don't mark the thread as FIXED: attribute the points to the person who fixed it for you by accepting their answer. If nobody did, write your own answer and accept it. If the question was invalid, delete it.

Comment: We should make a community wiki answer with eggyal, no ?

Comment: Ok. Sorry... I didn't knew that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is such a flagrant impossible sequence of queries, then it's time to think about a table (or index) corruption and to run the Mysql `CHECK` command.

In that case, running  `REPAIR TABLE members QUICK` did the trick.

Comment: Why do you edit my question and delete the FIXED in the title?

Comment: Read the comments of haylem : SO isn't a forum and we don't mark [FIXED] in the title. This answer was made with help from eggyal and that's the reason why I made it a community wiki answer (no reputation point for me).

Answer (score 0):

If the id is a varchar and the email is a varchar they might have surrounding spaces.

Comment: No, id is int and mail have no spaces

Comment: even if they have spaces - using like with % at beginning and and makes it irrelevant.

Comment: the % will match  the spaces but without them it wont match. But yes if the mail doesnt have spaces, then that wont fit